# debootstrap terminates partway through with "stdin: not in compressed format"

Tags: debian, arch-linux, system-installation, tar, dpkg

I'm on an Arch GNU/Linux system, fully up-to-date (both official repositories and from the AUR). I'm attempting to install a copy of Debian Wheezy so that I can chroot into it and work with the system. However, `debootstrap` (installed from the Arch User Repository, along with `gpg1` and `debian-archive-keyring`) is giving me weird results.

Versions:

```
$ debootstrap --version
debootstrap 1.0.60~bpo70+1

$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.

$ ar --version
GNU ar (GNU Binutils) 2.24
Copyright 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.

$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.18(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Working directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/alex/Development
```

Environment:

```
$ env
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
USER=alex
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
XDG_VTNR=1
LOGNAME=alex
PWD=/home/alex/Development
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
DISPLAY=:0
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-alex-eNzAWR/database
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=1617
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
GDMSESSION=gnome
USERNAME=alex
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
ANDROID_SWT=/usr/share/java
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-oFjTGqs5Bd,guid=321f3c380c7ed3446e9fb41f53bb8307
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/alex
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
WINDOWID=50331652
TERM=xterm
SESSION_MANAGER=local/null-ptr-exception:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1082,unix/null-ptr-exception:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1082
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
PATH=/home/alex/bin:/home/alex/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/alex/bin:/home/alex/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
XDG_SEAT=seat0
BROWSER=firefox
HOME=/home/alex
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring/gpg:0:1
TERMINATOR_UUID=urn:uuid:48777400-553b-46fe-ac51-6e52dfb1454f
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
OLDPWD=/home/alex/Development
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn
GREP_COLOR=1;32
PAGER=less
LESS=-R
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
ANTIGEN_DEFAULT_REPO_URL=https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git
ADOTDIR=/home/alex/.antigen
_=/usr/bin/env

    $ sudo env
[sudo] password for alex: 
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
DISPLAY=:0
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-alex-eNzAWR/database
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=xterm
PATH=/home/alex/bin:/home/alex/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/alex/bin:/home/alex/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
MAIL=/var/mail/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
USERNAME=root
HOME=/root
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
SUDO_USER=alex
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
```

And, of course, `debootstrap` itself:

```
$ sudo rm -r Debian/wheezy-amd64 # nuke a previous attempt from orbit

$ sudo sh -xe debootstrap --arch amd64 --foreign wheezy /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 http://http.debian.net/debian
+ VERSION=1.0.60~bpo70+1
+ unset TMP TEMP TMPDIR
+ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/java/jre/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
+ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/java/jre/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -x /debootstrap/debootstrap ']'
+ DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=/usr/share/debootstrap
+ DEVICES_TARGZ=/usr/share/debootstrap/devices.tar.gz
+ . /usr/share/debootstrap/functions
++ PROGRESS_NOW=0
++ PROGRESS_END=0
++ PROGRESS_NEXT=
++ PROGRESS_WHAT=
++ FINDDEBS_NEEDS_INDICES=false
++ SUPPORTED_VARIANTS=-
++ EXTRACTORS_SUPPORTED='dpkg-deb ar'
++ UMOUNT_DIRS=
++ in_path perl
++ local 'OLD_IFS=  
'
++ IFS=:
++ for dir in '$PATH'
++ '[' -x /usr/local/bin/perl ']'
++ for dir in '$PATH'
++ '[' -x /usr/bin/perl ']'
++ IFS='    
'
++ return 0
++ PKGDETAILS=pkgdetails_perl
++ N_EXIT_THINGS=0
++ trap exit_function 0
++ trap 'exit 129' 1
++ trap 'error 130 INTERRUPTED "Interrupt caught ... exiting"' 2
++ trap 'exit 131' 3
++ trap 'exit 143' 15
+ exec
+ LANG=C
+ USE_COMPONENTS=main
+ KEYRING=
+ DISABLE_KEYRING=
+ VARIANT=
+ ARCH=
+ HOST_ARCH=
+ HOST_OS=
+ KEEP_DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=
+ USE_DEBIANINSTALLER_INTERACTION=
+ SECOND_STAGE_ONLY=
+ PRINT_DEBS=
+ CHROOTDIR=
+ MAKE_TARBALL=
+ KEEP_DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=
+ EXTRACTOR_OVERRIDE=
+ UNPACK_TARBALL=
+ ADDITIONAL=
+ EXCLUDE=
+ VERBOSE=
+ CERTIFICATE=
+ CHECKCERTIF=
+ PRIVATEKEY=
+ DEF_MIRROR=http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
+ DEF_HTTPS_MIRROR=https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian
+ export LANG USE_COMPONENTS
+ umask 022
+ RESOLVE_DEPS=true
+ WHAT_TO_DO='finddebs dldebs first_stage second_stage'
+ '[' -z pkgdetails_perl ']'
+ '[' 6 '!=' 0 ']'
+ true
+ case "$1" in
+ '[' --arch = --arch -a -n amd64 ']'
+ ARCH=amd64
+ shift 2
+ true
+ case "$1" in
+ '[' '' '!=' true ']'
+ WHAT_TO_DO='finddebs dldebs first_stage'
+ shift
+ true
+ case "$1" in
+ break
+ '[' '' = true ']'
+ '[' -z wheezy ']'
+ '[' -z /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 ']'
+ SUITE=wheezy
+ TARGET=/home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64
+ USER_MIRROR=http://http.debian.net/debian
+ TARGET=/home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64
+ '[' home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 = /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 ']'
+ SCRIPT=/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/wheezy
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ in_path dpkg
+ local 'OLD_IFS=   
'
+ IFS=:
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/local/bin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /bin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/local/sbin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/sbin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /sbin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /opt/java/jre/bin/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/vendor_perl/dpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/core_perl/dpkg ']'
+ IFS='     
'
+ return 1
+ in_path udpkg
+ local 'OLD_IFS=   
'
+ IFS=:
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/local/bin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /bin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/local/sbin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/sbin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /sbin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /opt/java/jre/bin/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/vendor_perl/udpkg ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/core_perl/udpkg ']'
+ IFS='     
'
+ return 1
+ '[' -e /usr/share/debootstrap/arch ']'
++ cat /usr/share/debootstrap/arch
+ HOST_ARCH=amd64
+ HOST_OS=amd64
+ '[' -z amd64 ']'
+ '[' -z amd64 ']'
+ '[' -z amd64 ']'
+ '[' -z amd64 ']'
+ '[' amd64 = kfreebsd ']'
+ '[' amd64 = freebsd ']'
+ '[' /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 = / ']'
+ doing_variant scratchbox
+ '[' scratchbox = '' ']'
+ '[' scratchbox = - ']'
+ return 1
+ CHROOT_CMD='chroot /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ SHA_SIZE=256
+ in_path sha256sum
+ local 'OLD_IFS=   
'
+ IFS=:
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/local/bin/sha256sum ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/sha256sum ']'
+ IFS='     
'
+ return 0
+ DEBOOTSTRAP_CHECKSUM_FIELD=SHA256
+ export ARCH SUITE TARGET CHROOT_CMD SHA_SIZE DEBOOTSTRAP_CHECKSUM_FIELD
+ am_doing_phase first_stage second_stage
+ local x
+ for x in '"$@"'
+ echo ' finddebs dldebs first_stage '
+ grep -q ' first_stage '
+ return 0
+ in_path id
+ local 'OLD_IFS=   
'
+ IFS=:
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/local/bin/id ']'
+ for dir in '$PATH'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/id ']'
+ IFS='     
'
+ return 0
++ id -u
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ check_sane_mount /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64
+ mkdir -p /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64
+ case "$HOST_OS" in
+ mknod /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64/test-dev-null c 1 3
+ echo test
+ rm -f /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64/test-dev-null
+ SH=/bin/sh
+ '[' -x /bin/sh ']'
+ cat
+ chmod +x /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64/test-exec
+ /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64/test-exec
+ rm -f /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64/test-exec
+ return 0
+ '[' '!' -e /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/wheezy ']'
+ '[' /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 '!=' '' ']'
+ mkdir -p /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64/debootstrap
+ '[' '' = yes ']'
+ am_doing_phase printdebs
+ local x
+ for x in '"$@"'
+ echo ' finddebs dldebs first_stage '
+ grep -q ' printdebs '
+ return 1
+ exec
+ exec
+ exec
I: Retrieving Release 
I: Retrieving Release.gpg 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id ED6D65271AACF0FF15D123036FB2A1C265FFB764)
I: Retrieving Packages 
I: Validating Packages 
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Found additional required dependencies: insserv libbz2-1.0 libdb5.1 libsemanage1 libsemanage-common libslang2 libustr-1.0-1 
I: Found additional base dependencies: libept1.4.12 libgcrypt11 libgnutls26 libgpg-error0 libidn11 libnfnetlink0 libp11-kit0 libsqlite3-0 libtasn1-3 libxapian22 
I: Checking component main on http://http.debian.net/debian...
I: Retrieving libacl1 2.2.51-8
I: Validating libacl1 2.2.51-8
I: Retrieving adduser 3.113+nmu3
I: Validating adduser 3.113+nmu3
I: Retrieving apt 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Validating apt 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Retrieving apt-utils 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Validating apt-utils 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Retrieving libapt-inst1.5 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Validating libapt-inst1.5 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Retrieving libapt-pkg4.12 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Validating libapt-pkg4.12 0.9.7.9+deb7u1
I: Retrieving aptitude 0.6.8.2-1
I: Validating aptitude 0.6.8.2-1
I: Retrieving aptitude-common 0.6.8.2-1
I: Validating aptitude-common 0.6.8.2-1
I: Retrieving libattr1 1%3a2.4.46-8
I: Validating libattr1 1%3a2.4.46-8
I: Retrieving base-files 7.1wheezy5
I: Validating base-files 7.1wheezy5
I: Retrieving base-passwd 3.5.26
I: Validating base-passwd 3.5.26
I: Retrieving bash 4.2+dfsg-0.1
I: Validating bash 4.2+dfsg-0.1
I: Retrieving libboost-iostreams1.49.0 1.49.0-3.2
I: Validating libboost-iostreams1.49.0 1.49.0-3.2
I: Retrieving bsdmainutils 9.0.3
I: Validating bsdmainutils 9.0.3
I: Retrieving libbz2-1.0 1.0.6-4
I: Validating libbz2-1.0 1.0.6-4
I: Retrieving coreutils 8.13-3.5
I: Validating coreutils 8.13-3.5
I: Retrieving cpio 2.11+dfsg-0.1
I: Validating cpio 2.11+dfsg-0.1
I: Retrieving cron 3.0pl1-124
I: Validating cron 3.0pl1-124
I: Retrieving libcwidget3 0.5.16-3.4
I: Validating libcwidget3 0.5.16-3.4
I: Retrieving dash 0.5.7-3
I: Validating dash 0.5.7-3
I: Retrieving libdb5.1 5.1.29-5
I: Validating libdb5.1 5.1.29-5
I: Retrieving debconf 1.5.49
I: Validating debconf 1.5.49
I: Retrieving debconf-i18n 1.5.49
I: Validating debconf-i18n 1.5.49
I: Retrieving debian-archive-keyring 2012.4
I: Validating debian-archive-keyring 2012.4
I: Retrieving debianutils 4.3.2
I: Validating debianutils 4.3.2
I: Retrieving diffutils 1%3a3.2-6
I: Validating diffutils 1%3a3.2-6
I: Retrieving dmidecode 2.11-9
I: Validating dmidecode 2.11-9
I: Retrieving dpkg 1.16.12
I: Validating dpkg 1.16.12
I: Retrieving e2fslibs 1.42.5-1.1
I: Validating e2fslibs 1.42.5-1.1
I: Retrieving e2fsprogs 1.42.5-1.1
I: Validating e2fsprogs 1.42.5-1.1
I: Retrieving libcomerr2 1.42.5-1.1
I: Validating libcomerr2 1.42.5-1.1
I: Retrieving libss2 1.42.5-1.1
I: Validating libss2 1.42.5-1.1
I: Retrieving libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u1
I: Validating libc-bin 2.13-38+deb7u1
I: Retrieving libc6 2.13-38+deb7u1
I: Validating libc6 2.13-38+deb7u1
I: Retrieving multiarch-support 2.13-38+deb7u1
I: Validating multiarch-support 2.13-38+deb7u1
I: Retrieving findutils 4.4.2-4
I: Validating findutils 4.4.2-4
I: Retrieving gcc-4.7-base 4.7.2-5
I: Validating gcc-4.7-base 4.7.2-5
I: Retrieving libgcc1 1%3a4.7.2-5
I: Validating libgcc1 1%3a4.7.2-5
I: Retrieving libstdc++6 4.7.2-5
I: Validating libstdc++6 4.7.2-5
I: Retrieving libgdbm3 1.8.3-11
I: Validating libgdbm3 1.8.3-11
I: Retrieving gnupg 1.4.12-7+deb7u3
I: Validating gnupg 1.4.12-7+deb7u3
I: Retrieving gpgv 1.4.12-7+deb7u3
I: Validating gpgv 1.4.12-7+deb7u3
I: Retrieving libgnutls26 2.12.20-8+deb7u1
I: Validating libgnutls26 2.12.20-8+deb7u1
I: Retrieving grep 2.12-2
I: Validating grep 2.12-2
I: Retrieving groff-base 1.21-9
I: Validating groff-base 1.21-9
I: Retrieving gzip 1.5-1.1
I: Validating gzip 1.5-1.1
I: Retrieving hostname 3.11
I: Validating hostname 3.11
I: Retrieving ifupdown 0.7.8
I: Validating ifupdown 0.7.8
I: Retrieving insserv 1.14.0-5
I: Validating insserv 1.14.0-5
I: Retrieving iproute 20120521-3+b3
I: Validating iproute 20120521-3+b3
I: Retrieving iptables 1.4.14-3.1
I: Validating iptables 1.4.14-3.1
I: Retrieving iputils-ping 3%3a20101006-1+b1
I: Validating iputils-ping 3%3a20101006-1+b1
I: Retrieving isc-dhcp-client 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
I: Validating isc-dhcp-client 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
I: Retrieving isc-dhcp-common 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
I: Validating isc-dhcp-common 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
I: Retrieving kmod 9-3
I: Validating kmod 9-3
I: Retrieving libkmod2 9-3
I: Validating libkmod2 9-3
I: Retrieving libept1.4.12 1.0.9
I: Validating libept1.4.12 1.0.9
I: Retrieving libgcrypt11 1.5.0-5+deb7u1
I: Validating libgcrypt11 1.5.0-5+deb7u1
I: Retrieving libgpg-error0 1.10-3.1
I: Validating libgpg-error0 1.10-3.1
I: Retrieving libidn11 1.25-2
I: Validating libidn11 1.25-2
I: Retrieving liblocale-gettext-perl 1.05-7+b1
I: Validating liblocale-gettext-perl 1.05-7+b1
I: Retrieving libnfnetlink0 1.0.0-1.1
I: Validating libnfnetlink0 1.0.0-1.1
I: Retrieving libpipeline1 1.2.1-1
I: Validating libpipeline1 1.2.1-1
I: Retrieving libselinux1 2.1.9-5
I: Validating libselinux1 2.1.9-5
I: Retrieving libsemanage-common 2.1.6-6
I: Validating libsemanage-common 2.1.6-6
I: Retrieving libsemanage1 2.1.6-6
I: Validating libsemanage1 2.1.6-6
I: Retrieving libsepol1 2.1.4-3
I: Validating libsepol1 2.1.4-3
I: Retrieving libsigc++-2.0-0c2a 2.2.10-0.2
I: Validating libsigc++-2.0-0c2a 2.2.10-0.2
I: Retrieving libtasn1-3 2.13-2
I: Validating libtasn1-3 2.13-2
I: Retrieving libtext-charwidth-perl 0.04-7+b1
I: Validating libtext-charwidth-perl 0.04-7+b1
I: Retrieving libtext-iconv-perl 1.7-5
I: Validating libtext-iconv-perl 1.7-5
I: Retrieving libtext-wrapi18n-perl 0.06-7
I: Validating libtext-wrapi18n-perl 0.06-7
I: Retrieving libusb-0.1-4 2%3a0.1.12-20+nmu1
I: Validating libusb-0.1-4 2%3a0.1.12-20+nmu1
I: Retrieving logrotate 3.8.1-4
I: Validating logrotate 3.8.1-4
I: Retrieving lsb-base 4.1+Debian8+deb7u1
I: Validating lsb-base 4.1+Debian8+deb7u1
I: Retrieving man-db 2.6.2-1
I: Validating man-db 2.6.2-1
I: Retrieving manpages 3.44-1
I: Validating manpages 3.44-1
I: Retrieving mawk 1.3.3-17
I: Validating mawk 1.3.3-17
I: Retrieving nano 2.2.6-1+b1
I: Validating nano 2.2.6-1+b1
I: Retrieving libncurses5 5.9-10
I: Validating libncurses5 5.9-10
I: Retrieving libncursesw5 5.9-10
I: Validating libncursesw5 5.9-10
I: Retrieving libtinfo5 5.9-10
I: Validating libtinfo5 5.9-10
I: Retrieving ncurses-base 5.9-10
I: Validating ncurses-base 5.9-10
I: Retrieving ncurses-bin 5.9-10
I: Validating ncurses-bin 5.9-10
I: Retrieving net-tools 1.60-24.2
I: Validating net-tools 1.60-24.2
I: Retrieving netbase 5.0
I: Validating netbase 5.0
I: Retrieving netcat-traditional 1.10-40
I: Validating netcat-traditional 1.10-40
I: Retrieving libnewt0.52 0.52.14-11.1
I: Validating libnewt0.52 0.52.14-11.1
I: Retrieving whiptail 0.52.14-11.1
I: Validating whiptail 0.52.14-11.1
I: Retrieving libssl1.0.0 1.0.1e-2+deb7u7
I: Validating libssl1.0.0 1.0.1e-2+deb7u7
I: Retrieving libp11-kit0 0.12-3
I: Validating libp11-kit0 0.12-3
I: Retrieving libpam-modules 1.1.3-7.1
I: Validating libpam-modules 1.1.3-7.1
I: Retrieving libpam-modules-bin 1.1.3-7.1
I: Validating libpam-modules-bin 1.1.3-7.1
I: Retrieving libpam-runtime 1.1.3-7.1
I: Validating libpam-runtime 1.1.3-7.1
I: Retrieving libpam0g 1.1.3-7.1
I: Validating libpam0g 1.1.3-7.1
I: Retrieving perl-base 5.14.2-21+deb7u1
I: Validating perl-base 5.14.2-21+deb7u1
I: Retrieving libpopt0 1.16-7
I: Validating libpopt0 1.16-7
I: Retrieving libprocps0 1%3a3.3.3-3
I: Validating libprocps0 1%3a3.3.3-3
I: Retrieving procps 1%3a3.3.3-3
I: Validating procps 1%3a3.3.3-3
I: Retrieving libreadline6 6.2+dfsg-0.1
I: Validating libreadline6 6.2+dfsg-0.1
I: Retrieving readline-common 6.2+dfsg-0.1
I: Validating readline-common 6.2+dfsg-0.1
I: Retrieving rsyslog 5.8.11-3
I: Validating rsyslog 5.8.11-3
I: Retrieving sed 4.2.1-10
I: Validating sed 4.2.1-10
I: Retrieving sensible-utils 0.0.7
I: Validating sensible-utils 0.0.7
I: Retrieving login 1%3a4.1.5.1-1
I: Validating login 1%3a4.1.5.1-1
I: Retrieving passwd 1%3a4.1.5.1-1
I: Validating passwd 1%3a4.1.5.1-1
I: Retrieving libslang2 2.2.4-15
I: Validating libslang2 2.2.4-15
I: Retrieving libsqlite3-0 3.7.13-1+deb7u1
I: Validating libsqlite3-0 3.7.13-1+deb7u1
I: Retrieving initscripts 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Validating initscripts 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Retrieving sysv-rc 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Validating sysv-rc 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Retrieving sysvinit 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Validating sysvinit 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Retrieving sysvinit-utils 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Validating sysvinit-utils 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
I: Retrieving tar 1.26+dfsg-0.1
I: Validating tar 1.26+dfsg-0.1
I: Retrieving tasksel 3.14.1
I: Validating tasksel 3.14.1
I: Retrieving tasksel-data 3.14.1
I: Validating tasksel-data 3.14.1
I: Retrieving info 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
I: Validating info 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
I: Retrieving install-info 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
I: Validating install-info 4.13a.dfsg.1-10
I: Retrieving traceroute 1%3a2.0.18-3
I: Validating traceroute 1%3a2.0.18-3
I: Retrieving tzdata 2014a-0wheezy1
I: Validating tzdata 2014a-0wheezy1
I: Retrieving libudev0 175-7.2
I: Validating libudev0 175-7.2
I: Retrieving udev 175-7.2
I: Validating udev 175-7.2
I: Retrieving libustr-1.0-1 1.0.4-3
I: Validating libustr-1.0-1 1.0.4-3
I: Retrieving bsdutils 1%3a2.20.1-5.3
I: Validating bsdutils 1%3a2.20.1-5.3
I: Retrieving libblkid1 2.20.1-5.3
I: Validating libblkid1 2.20.1-5.3
I: Retrieving libmount1 2.20.1-5.3
I: Validating libmount1 2.20.1-5.3
I: Retrieving libuuid1 2.20.1-5.3
I: Validating libuuid1 2.20.1-5.3
I: Retrieving mount 2.20.1-5.3
I: Validating mount 2.20.1-5.3
I: Retrieving util-linux 2.20.1-5.3
I: Validating util-linux 2.20.1-5.3
I: Retrieving vim-common 2%3a7.3.547-7
I: Validating vim-common 2%3a7.3.547-7
I: Retrieving vim-tiny 2%3a7.3.547-7
I: Validating vim-tiny 2%3a7.3.547-7
I: Retrieving wget 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
I: Validating wget 1.13.4-3+deb7u1
I: Retrieving libxapian22 1.2.12-2
I: Validating libxapian22 1.2.12-2
I: Retrieving liblzma5 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2
I: Validating liblzma5 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2
I: Retrieving xz-utils 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2
I: Validating xz-utils 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2
I: Retrieving zlib1g 1%3a1.2.7.dfsg-13
I: Validating zlib1g 1%3a1.2.7.dfsg-13
I: Chosen extractor for .deb packages: ar
I: Extracting libacl1...
```

Unfortunately, I've run out of characters in this question. So: [here is the output of `cat Debian/wheezy-amd64/debootstrap/debootstrap.log`](https://gist.github.com/strugee/9de78f2beeb77b23bcfe) (warning: 2MB!), and [here is the output of `tree Debian/wheezy-amd64`](https://gist.github.com/strugee/4cc4ea783924efe0641e).

Here are the last few lines of the debootstrap log. The file `libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb` is downloaded from http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/a/acl/libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb.

```
+ printf 'I: Extracting %s...\n' libacl1
+ extract_deb_data .//var/cache/apt/archives/libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb
+ extract_ar_deb_data .//var/cache/apt/archives/libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb
+ local pkg=.//var/cache/apt/archives/libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb
++ ar -t .//var/cache/apt/archives/libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb
++ grep '^data.tar'
+ local tarball=data.tar.gz
+ case "$tarball" in
+ cat_cmd=zcat
+ type zcat
+ ar -p .//var/cache/apt/archives/libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb data.tar.gz
+ zcat
+ tar -xf -
stdin: not in compressed format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
+ exit_function
+ local n=0
+ '[' 0 -lt 0 ']'
+ N_EXIT_THINGS=0
```

What is causing `debootstrap` to fail like this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe Arch's tar doesn't support some compression format that Debian's does? `libacl1` and `adduser` in wheezy are boring old `.tar.gz` though. These logs aren't very informative because they're missing the file name. Please run `sh -xe debootstrap --arch amd64 --foreign wheezy /home/alex/Development/Debian/wheezy-amd64 http://http.debian.net/debian` to get a more thorough log.

Comment: I've found that Arch's default `PATH` definition doesn't work for Debian. Apparently debootstrap inherits that variable and expects it to have the right things. It might be unrelated, but you could try adding all the usual `/bin` and `/sbin` variants that Arch doesn't use.

Comment: @Gilles sorry, I missed this for some reason. I'll run that as soon as I can (the affected machine is at a different house right now). @ams I doubt that's the problem, as `/bin`, `/sbin` et. al. are all symlinks to `/usr/bin`. at least if you have the `filesystem` package properly installed.

Comment: @Gilles added. hopefully the extra debug info is helpful.

Comment: That extraction looks like it should work. What is the `zcat` command on your system — it should be a hard or symbolic link of `gzip`? Run `ar -p libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb data.tar.gz | file -` and `ar -p libacl1_2.2.51-8_amd64.deb data.tar.gz | zcat | file -`, do they show “gzip compressed data” and “tar archive” (or minor variations)?